# Why is it so hard to find solutions in mathstackexchange

Tags: support, bug

I was advised that this site has people who can answer and are interested in research. But I asked questions, no one bothers to look. So I edit thinking I might be the problem. I realise there maybe MathJax formatting error but I've fixed them, wait again. So I decide to tackle the solution my self, I ask a reduced question which again no one bothers. Is there anything wrong with the questions?

- [Question 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488771/convex-optimization-of-order-2-polynomial?noredirect=1)
- [Question 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4489035/what-is-the-derivation-of-frac12x2-top-ax2)

so I tell the one who told me to ask here to look if I have an error he says the question is fine and votes me +1 for asking a good question. I am sorry guys I invested so much time to learn mathjax so I could ask a question mathematicians understand but something happened :(. or maybe it's my name, should I change it?

Comment: (just a remark: this Question is more about getting people to answer, not about searching)

Answer (score 9):

You posted Question 1 ten hours ago (as of now), and you quickly got comments pointing out mistakes in the post (which, to your credit, you seem to acknowledge and fix to some extent).  On its face the problem you pose could be globally minimizing a polynomial of degree 4 (not 2).  So for fixed $n$ I'd be inclined to treat the problem with polynomial algebra and calculus rather than linear algebra.  In any case it seems premature to say "no one bothers" when you did get some attention for your problem in less than a day.

Rather than post a new "reduced" version of your problem, it would perhaps be better to include that write-up in your original Question.  It would at least provide evidence to Readers that you are converging on a proper problem statement and have thought through the basis elements of formulation.  Readers are understandably discouraged when the Question undergoes so many edits so quickly (more than a dozen edits so far).

Comment: Thank you for you suggestions. i will try that

Answer (score 3):

- "Question 1" is okay, nothing special but probably won't be closed or downvoted
- "Question 2" shows little if any effort, and has been flagged and downvoted for that reason. It has some chance of being closed unless you can show some prior working or other contexts.
- Your username isn't explicitly offensive or political, so it is almost sure that nobody will remember it or flag it for moderator attention.

In general, Mathematics SE gets a lot of posts and a lot of them get almost no attention, let alone votes and answers.

If you have the reputation, you can add a bounty to "advertise" for attention, but this is no guarantee you'll get any response.

Fact is, there's way more questioning than there is answering, because posting questions is a lot easier than posting (useful, reasonable, of suitable quality) answers.

You could try adding more detail of what you've done so far to solve the problems, make sure they're tagged sensibly, and have a title that accurately describes the content, but beyond that, you're on the great roulette wheel of hoping the right person sees the post at the right time.

Comment: i will take this into consideration.